# How to enable WCF Service Discovery when using file-less activation?

Tags: wcf, activation, service-discovery

G'day guys,

How do I go about enabling service discovering when using WCF's file-less service activation? With this approach it doesn't seem possible to specify explicit endpoint types or a behaviorConfiguration?

My current attempt is as follows but service discovery still is not working:

```
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="Default" transactionFlow="true">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None">
        </transport>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<protocolMapping>
  <clear/>
  <add scheme="https" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="Default" />
</protocolMapping>

<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
      <serviceDiscovery/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>

  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <endpointDiscovery enabled="true">
        <scopes>
          <add scope="http://XPS/MvcApplication/Service/"/>
        </scopes>
      </endpointDiscovery>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>

<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true">
  <serviceActivations>
    <add service="RegistrationService" factory="Core.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory" relativeAddress="RegistrationService.svc" />
    <add service="EventService" factory="Core.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory" relativeAddress="EventService.svc" />
    <add service="ShoppingService" factory="Core.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory" relativeAddress="ShoppingService.svc" />
  </serviceActivations>
</serviceHostingEnvironment>
```

Comment: Are the services running? (i.e. can you browse the service page)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the web.config.

```
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Comment: Ha! No, I'm pretty sure giving my service behavior the name empty string isn't going to fix my problem...

Answer (score 0):

This question is a year old but for the sake of others who may have this question here's the answer:

Dispite the fact that you are using WCF fileless activation, you still need a `services` node in your `system.serviceModel` configuration section because you are required to explicitly add the discovery endpoint to each service you wish to make discoverable.

```
<services>
  <service name="RegistrationService">
    <endpoint binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="IRegistrationService"/>
    <endpoint kind="udpDiscoveryEndpoint"/>
  </service>
</services>
```

The above configuration snippet will add a discovery endpoint to your RegistrationService (I'm assuming you have an explicit service contract named IRegistrationService).

Note also, with the addition of a service configuration node for the RegistrationService you will need to add any data endpoints explicitly.